# Approximating a function at a value

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Consider $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Then given a derivative $f'(x_0)$, we have

> $f(x) \approx f'(x_0)(x - x_0) + f(x_0).$

Attempt at deriving the approximation above:

The derivative of $f$ at $x_0$ (if it exists) is given by $$f'(x_0) = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} \\ \iff \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} - f'(x_0) = 0 \\ \iff \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} - \lim_{h\to0}f'(x_0) = 0 \\ \iff  \lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} - f'(x_0)\right) = 0 \\ \iff \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)h}{h} = 0 \\ \iff  \lim_{h\to0}\frac{|f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)h|}{|h|} = 0 \\ \iff \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{|f(x) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(x - x_0)|}{|x - x_0|} = 0 \\ \iff \frac{\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to x_0}}|f(x) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(x - x_0)|}{\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to x_0}}|x - x_0|} = 0 \\ \iff \frac{\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to x_0}}|f(x) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(x - x_0)|}{|x - x_0|} = 0 \\ \iff \lim_{x\to x_0}|f(x) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(x - x_0)| = 0|x - x_0| \\ \iff \lim_{x\to x_0}|\color{blue}{f(x)} - \color{red}{(f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0))}| = 0 $$

We can rewrite the last expression in the chain above as

$ \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0 \text{ s.t. } |x - x_0| < \delta \implies ||\color{blue}{f(x)} - \color{red}{(f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0))}| - 0| < \epsilon \\ \iff \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0 \text{ s.t. } |x - x_0| < \delta \implies |\color{blue}{f(x)} - \color{red}{(f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0))}|  < \epsilon \\ \iff \text{for values of $x$ very close to $x_0$, the distance between $\color{blue}{f(x)} $ and $\color{red}{f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0)}$ is less than $\epsilon$}$

My questions:

1. Is the chain of biconditionals above correct?
2. $|\color{blue}{f(x)} - \color{red}{(f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0))}|  < \epsilon$ is true for all $\epsilon > 0$. Since the distance cannot be negative and anything greater than $0$ is $\epsilon$, it must be the case that $|\color{blue}{f(x)} - \color{red}{(f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0))}| = 0$. So how do they get $\color{blue}{f(x)} \approx \color{red}{f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0)}$ instead of $\color{blue}{f(x)} = \color{red}{f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0)}$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $f\approx f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + f(x_0)$ only holds for $x\approx x_0$.

The seventh equivalence is wrong, since you can't split the limit to the numerator and denominator. Also $\lim_{x\to x_0} \lvert x-x_0\rvert \neq \lvert x-x_0\rvert.$

To your second question: The term $\lvert f(x)-(f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0))\rvert$ is only smaller than $\epsilon$ if $x$ is sufficiently close to $x_0$, i.e. $\lvert x-x_0\rvert < \delta$. As $\epsilon$ goes to $0$, $x$ has to approach $x_0$ so you end up with $\lvert f(x_0) - (f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x_0 -x_0))\rvert = 0$ which is obviously true. Your reasoning would only be correct if the value for $x$ would be independent of $\epsilon$.

Comment: $x \approx x_0 \implies \lvert f(x_0) - (f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x_0 -x_0))\rvert = 0$, correct? Is my book saying something somewhat different in the following screenshot: https://ibb.co/SRnk8XL

Comment: $\lvert f(x_0) - (f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x_0-x_0))\rvert$ is zero because $x_0 - x_0 = 0$ and $f(x_0) -f(x_0)=0$. Your book is saying that $x\approx x_0 \Rightarrow \lvert f(x) - (f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0))\rvert \approx 0$.